# Segmentation fault (core dumped) only bigger input

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

My code works perfectly if the seive(n) is  1000000. If seive(n) is more than 10000000, it shows me segmentation fault (core dumped).I've read about segmentation fault. But i couldn't solve with that.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    using namespace std;


    int seive(long int n)
    {
        long int A[n];

        for (long int i = 2; i <= n; i += 1)
        {
            A[i] = i;
        }
        long int root = (int)sqrt(n);

        for(int j = 2; j <= root; j++)
        {

            for(int k = 2*j; k < n ; k = k + j)
            {       
                A[k] = 0;
            }
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (int l = 2; l < n; ++l)
        {
            if(A[l] != 0) count++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", count);

    }

    int main()
    {
        seive( 1000000);
    }
```

Comment: Your compiler probably allocates VLAs on the stack, which presumably cannot handle `10000000 * sizeof(long int)`.

Comment: It might occur stack overflow. If you use linux, put command 'ulimit -a' and check stack size. I think you should use malloc instead of using array.

Comment: Assuming `long` is 64bit on this platform, `10000000` specified as `n` in `long A[n];` is going to mandate 76.3 MB of automatic storage space (stack), which I'm going to go ahead and bet you are *not* providing. And it isn't needed anyway. A sieve doesn't need anything larger than a bit-per-element, though `char` is much more frequently used. Its the *indexes* enumerating a sieve that are significant; the content of each slot need be nothing more than something that can represent "true" or "false"

Answer (score 3):

> long int A[n];

This is an array on the stack. It is really big, if N is big. Your stack is not big enough to hold it in those cases and you will get a stack overflow error.

Solutions include:

Dynamically allocating memory: long int *A = (long int *)malloc(n*sizeof(long int));

Dynamically allocating memory C++ style: long int *A = new long int[n];

<strike>Using a statically allocated buffer (that's not on the stack, then): static long int A[n];</strike>

<strike>Making it global: move that line up 3 lines.</strike>

Comment: VLAs can't have static storage duration, so the last two "solutions" *aren't*. The first (dynamic allocation), is doable. Remember, `n` is passed in; not a fixed constant.

Comment: and question is tagged c++ so using malloc is not the first choice

Comment: @Randomizer If you want to go strict C++ it doesn't support VLAs at all.

Comment: @WhozCraig Good point. For the general "where do I put my array" they are otherwise good places.

Comment: @dascandy I would have noted the no-VLA route regarding C++ except the OP's compiler obviously does support them via extension (probably gcc). Otherwise this would be a completely different question.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is trying to allocate an array with large number of elements on stack (stack memory)

```
long int A[n];
```

In general you will be able to allocate a larger array on heap using

```
int *A = new int[n]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your automatic storage space is being taxed beyond its limits on your platform for a number of reasons.

First, each element is needlessly 63 bits larger than it needs to be, assuming your platform `unsigned long int` is 64bit. A sieve normally needs to represent only one of two values "true" or "false". A array of `bool` would suffice for this with some minor tweaking to your algorithm.

Second, though the first item is important, it isn't the dominant factor in the size of your array. That privilege belongs to `n`, the top-limit on your quest. Your requesting a significant amount of space in automatic storage. Assuming you addressed the first and the representation of `bool` on your platform ere a single byte, A flags-array of `10000000` entries would still require approx. 9.54 MB of automatic storage which is no laughing matter.

The solution is *dynamic* storage, and can be accomplished a number of ways, some of which are:

- Use `malloc(sizeof(bool)*(n+1))` (discouraged in modern C++ programs)
- Use `new bool[n+1]]` (better, but still not great)
- Use an [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) container like [`std::vector<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (now we're getting somewhere)

A very simple thrown-together sieve example that employs the above appears below. You can improve on this *significantly* with optimized logic regarding even numbers (no need to even keep them), etc. But that isn't the point. The point is using dynamic storage, preferably something with automatic lifetime, which `std::vector<>` does for you nicely.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

unsigned long int sieve(unsigned long int N)
{
    std::vector<bool> vec(N+1,true);
    unsigned long int res = 1;
    const unsigned long int SR = std::floor(std::sqrtl(static_cast<long double>(N)));

    for (unsigned long int i=2; i<=SR; ++i)
    {
        if (vec[i])
        {
            ++res;
            for (unsigned long int j=(i << 1); j<=N; j+=i)
                vec[j] = false;
        }
    }

    for (unsigned long int i=SR+1; i<=N; ++i)
    {
        if (vec[i])
            ++res;
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sieve(10000000) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
664580
```

which I believe is correct unless you're of the kind that disregards `1` (some do, dunno why), in which case it's off by one.

Comment: Prime numbers are defined as "divisible by exactly two (distinct) numbers". 1 is not. Also, having 1 as a prime makes some proofs harder while making none easier, so for an arbitrary choice it's logical. Also, don't use std::vector<bool> as it is packed, and will perform much slower.